# Paragraph curiosity

Tags: english, language

What is curious about this paragraph? Alright, I'm not going to make it lipogrammatic: 'Here, have seven e's!' Just in case, I'll put every letter in -  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ! So, it must be something else. Yes, there is punctuation, of all sorts. What you're looking for is not about letter frequency, though this property is strange to have in large or long paragraphs. So, what is it? That's for you to answer!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The property is:

> the paragraph doesn't contain any articles - the words "the", "a" and "an". Usually, articles are essential in a paragraph of writing, but here they've been avoided.

Answer (score 0):

A second property of this paragraph, although probably not the one intended:

> This paragraph does not contain a semicolon (;), although it implies that it contains all commonly used punctuation.